# maykinmedia / dual-listbox no value passed after form submission

Tags: codeigniter

im trying to implement maykinmedia/dual-listbox in my CI application, the plugin is working fine, but when i submit the form, the $_POST variable doesn't contain any value. I can provide the javascript part, but it is the standard init for the plugin, the data are passed by the CI controller. Please help. Below the html part, in this case is missing the name from the select tag, but even adding it, doesn't change the result.

```php
<select id="data" class="kt-dual-listbox" multiple
                            data-available-title="Source Options"
                            data-selected-title="Destination Options"
                            data-add="<i class='flaticon2-next'></i>"
                            data-remove="<i class='flaticon2-back'></i>"
                            data-add-all="<i class='flaticon2-fast-next'></i>"
                            data-remove-all="<i class='flaticon2-fast-back'></i>"
                    >
                    <?php foreach ($contents_data_data as $content_data_data){ ?>
                        <option value="<?= $content_data_data->id ?>"><?= $content_data_data->name ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Class definition

```js
var KTDualListbox = function () {

    // Private functions
    var initDualListbox = function () {
        // Dual Listbox
        var listBoxes = $('.kt-dual-listbox');

        listBoxes.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var id = '#' + $this.attr('id');
            // get titles
            var availableTitle = ($this.attr('data-available-title') != null) ? $this.attr('data-available-title') : 'Available options';
            var selectedTitle = ($this.attr('data-selected-title') != null) ? $this.attr('data-selected-title') : 'Selected options';

            // get button labels
            var addLabel = ($this.attr('data-add') != null) ? $this.attr('data-add') : 'Add';
            var removeLabel = ($this.attr('data-remove') != null) ? $this.attr('data-remove') : 'Remove';
            var addAllLabel = ($this.attr('data-add-all') != null) ? $this.attr('data-add-all') : 'Add All';
            var removeAllLabel = ($this.attr('data-remove-all') != null) ? $this.attr('data-remove-all') : 'Remove All';

            // get options
            var options = [];
            $this.children('option').each(function(){
                var value = $(this).val();
                var label = $(this).text();
                var selected = ($(this).is(':selected')) ? true : false;
                options.push({ text: label, value: value, selected: selected });
            });

            // get search option
            var search = ($this.attr('data-search') != null) ? $this.attr('data-search') : "";

            // clear duplicates
            $this.empty();

            // init dual listbox
            var dualListBox = new DualListbox(id,{
                addEvent: function(value) {
                    console.log(value);
                },
                removeEvent: function(value) {
                    console.log(value);
                },
                availableTitle: availableTitle,
                selectedTitle: selectedTitle,
                addButtonText: addLabel,
                removeButtonText: removeLabel,
                addAllButtonText: addAllLabel,
                removeAllButtonText: removeAllLabel,
                options: options
            });

            if (search == "false"){
                dualListBox.search.classList.add('dual-listbox__search--hidden');
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        // public functions
        init: function() {
            initDualListbox();
        }
    };
}();
```

Comment: you need to set a name attribute `<select name="your_db_col_name">`

Comment: Hello Vickel, thanks for your answer; but as i already wrote even adding the name still doesn't work. If i print_r the $_POST variable after submit  i can see all others fields, but not the one from the duallist box. If i add a normal select  it is working. In teh project im also using angularjs, can the issue be a result of some conflict? thank you

Comment: Oh, I missed that part... maybe you should add the relevant part of the javascript (is it sent via ajax?) to your question (not as comment)

Comment: just added, no it is sent to the CI controller in which i use form validation to verify the submission.

Comment: don't know the plugin, but looking at their github (https://github.com/maykinmedia/dual-listbox), it seems you need to get the POST vars from the 2nd Listbox (selected options)

Comment: you mean in  javascript? because on the HTML i just have 1 select; if i use a normal select with the multiple option i get the value in the $_POST. Anyway thanks for your help, really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

commenting this line

```
$this.empty();
```

in the javascript file, solve the issue; but then the source options list will show 2 times the same option.